# Continuous Binary Search over Metric Space

Tags: binary-search, metrics, continuous

I am studying the binary search problem on continuous intervals using a non-linear distance metric `D`. In this interval search, I'm restricting myself to binary queries, meaning the only information available is whether the current `x` is less than `x∗`. **The goal is to find an ε-approximation `x'` to the actual result `x*` while making sure that `D(x', x∗) ≤ ε`**. I'm also working on establishing upper and lower bounds on query complexity for this problem.

By distance metric, I mean a function `D` that measures the distance/difference between any two points of the interval, `D(·,·) → R0+ ∪ ∞`. [This article](https://medium.com/dscjssstu/generalising-binary-search-b58f4bf4e176) presents an algorithm closely related to my work, involving continuous search and ε-approximated output.

```
my_sqrt(x):
    epsilon = 0.001 
    L = 0, R = x
    while (R - L > epsilon):
        mid = L + (R - L)/2
        if (mid*mid <= x):
            L = mid
        else
            R = mid
    return L + (R - L)/2
```

It utilizes a linear function (absolute value) for the distance metric, but my focus is mainly on incorporating a non-linear metric, such as the square root of log ratio. For any pair of points `x` and `x'` within the interval, the distance is computed as `D(x, x') = sqrt(log(x) - log(x')) = sqrt(log(x/x'))`.

I'm thinking of calling this problem **metric binary search**, but I'm curious if there's any existing research or a commonly used term for this type of algorithm. Additionally, I'm interested in finding out if there's been any study on an unbounded version of this algorithm (like how the binary search extends to unbounded binary search).

Comment: Hang on.  If you have a continuous interval, then every point is included.  There's nothing to search for -- if a point is in the interval, then it's found.  What you have posted there is the Newton-Raphson method for finding square roots.

Comment: Sorry if I confuse you. The problem is trying to find a point that is ε away from the desired ground truth point `x*` via a binary search approach, i.e., continuously checking if the middle point of the current interval is greater or less than the ground truth point through some magic query and then determine which subinterval that `x*` resides in (and stop when it found such x').  
Newton methods require distance metrics to be continuous and result depends on the starting, while I want to relax such an assumption. 
square roots is just an example showing that metric can be subadditive.

Comment: I'm still confused, which probably means I should stop commenting.  Binary search works well for well-behaved functions with well-behaved first derivatives.  With non-linear functions, or discontinuous functions, or functions were the first derivative has an inflection point, binary searching can have quite bad behavior, right?  I'm not sure it can be generalized as much as you want.